# Logout / Timeout redirect ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In my ASP.net core site, after 20 minutes of inactivity, the session expires, and on the next action that the user performs that requires authentication, the site redirects back to /Account/Login. The problem is, I'd like to redirect back to a different page depending on the session that was expired.

For example, people log in to my website at https://example.com/Account/Login?appId=12345. However, when the session expires and the user is redirected back to the login page, the appId=12345 is stripped. (12345 could be anything depending on the user). I'm not sure how to include a custom parameter in the redirect URL unique to each session.

Here's how I have the timeout currently configured in Startup.cs:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
      AutomaticChallenge = true,
      SlidingExpiration = true,
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)
      LoginPath = "/Account/Login"
 });
```

I was asked for my httpget and httppost login methods, so here is a very stripped down version (especially the POST method) of them:

```
 [RequireHttps]
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/", // The path to direct to after the login is complete
                               bool activated = false, // If the screen should prompt that the account has been activated. This flag is used from email activation only
                               string email = null,    // To pre-populate an e-mail address in the username field
                               bool interactive = false,    // Interactive login (ask for username first, then password OR create user)
                               string applicationId = null, // An application id (for tblApplications) to format the screen and log directly in to an application
                               string errorMessage = null
                              ) {

        LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel();

        // Pre-set Username
        model.EmailAddress = email;

        // Application
        Guid applicationGuid;
        if (applicationId != null && Guid.TryParse(applicationId, out applicationGuid)) {
            tblApplication application = dbo.GetSingle<tblApplication>(x => x.ApplicationGuid == applicationGuid);
            if (application != null) {
                model.applicationId = applicationId;
                model.ApplicationTitle = application.Title;

                List<tblSettings> settings = dbo.GetList<tblSettings>(x => x.ApplicationId == application.ApplicationId).ToList();
                if (settings.Where(x => x.SettingMasterId == 41 && x.SettingValue1 == "1").Count() > 0) model.showHeader = false;
                if (settings.Where(x => x.SettingMasterId == 42 && x.SettingValue1 == "1").Count() > 0) model.showFooter = false;
                if (settings.Any(x => x.SettingMasterId == 52)) model.LoginHeader = settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SettingMasterId == 52).SettingValue1;
                if (settings.Any(x => x.SettingMasterId == 63 && x.SettingValue1 != null)) model.themeId = int.Parse(settings.Where(x => x.SettingMasterId == 63 && x.SettingValue1 != null).FirstOrDefault().SettingValue1);
                if (settings.Where(x => x.SettingMasterId == 67 && x.SettingValue1 == "1").Count() > 0) model.Interactive = true;
            }
        }

        // Return URL after login successful
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        // Activation message from security provider 
        if (activated) model.activated = true;

        // Interactive
        if (interactive) model.Interactive = true;

        // Error Message
        if (errorMessage != null) model.BannerErrorMessage = errorMessage;

        // Return to form
        return View(model);
    }

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel vm, string returnUrl = null) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            tblIdentity identity = null;
            try {

                // Pull the client identity record from the database
                identity = dbo.ExecuteQuery<tblIdentity>(x => x.ClientId == vm.EmailAddress).FirstOrDefault();
                if (identity == null)
                    throw new Exception("Invalid Email or Password");

                // ** Authentication Code here. On failure, throw exception

                if (user.EmailVerified == null || user.EmailVerified == false) {
                    // ** Code for email address not verified
                    return RedirectToAction("AccountNotVerified", model);
                }
                else {
                    // Call the login procedure to create cookes
                    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = await login(identity, user.UserId, user.FullName, user.Email, vm.applicationId);

                    // Sign user into cookie middleware
                    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal);

                    // Redirect back to the return url
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
            }
        }
        return View(vm);
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> login(tblClientIdentity identity, string userId, string fullName, string email, string applicationId = null) {

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                                                                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId),
                                                                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, fullName),
                                                                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email)},
                                                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

        // Application
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationId) == false) {
            Guid applicationGuid;
            if (Guid.TryParse(applicationId, out applicationGuid)) {
                tblApplication application = dbo.GetSingle<tblApplication>(x => x.ApplicationGuid == applicationGuid);
                if (application != null) {
                    claimsPrincipal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("ApplicationId", applicationId, ClaimValueTypes.String, "https://example.com"));
                    HttpContext.Session.SetString("ApplicationId", applicationId);
                }
                else {
                    if (HttpContext != null) HttpContext.Session.Remove("ApplicationId");
                    RedirectToAction("Login", "Account", new { ErrorMessage = "The application could not be loaded" });
                }
            }
            else {
                if (HttpContext != null) HttpContext.Session.Remove("ApplicationId");
            }
        }
        else {
            if (HttpContext != null) HttpContext.Session.Remove("ApplicationId");
        }
        return claimsPrincipal;
    }
```

Comment: Can you figure out the correct appId *after* the user is logged in? How do the users get to the correct login in the first place?

Comment: No, the appId is in the URL when the user logs in. Then, during login, the appId is added as a claim (User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "appId")) and then referenced throughout the website. Users get to the correct login in the first place via direct link

Comment: Could you show your login action methods - both HttpGet and HttpPost?

Comment: @Win I updated my question with a basic version of my httpget and httppost methods

Comment: You could look at the [OnRedirectToLogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttologin) handler.